# Determine products of redox-reaction (KMnO4) by Standard electrode potential

Tags: redox

I want to figure out a way how to determine the products of a redox-reaction by looking at the documented Standard electrode potential (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page))). But with my "way" I have some trouble/contradictions with common redox reaction, in my case the reduction of $\ce{MnO4-}.

Here is my procedure for the reduction of $\ce{MnO4-}$:

1. Collect all available reactions with their Standard Potential:* 
   \begin{align}
   \ce{MnO4- + 2H2O + 4e- &-> MnO2 + 4OH-}& 
   E(\text{Red})&= \pu{0.83 V}\tag{a}\label{a}\\
   \ce{MnO4- + H+ + e- &-> HMnO4^-}
   & E(\text{Red}) &= \pu{0.72 V}\tag{b}\label{b}\\
   \ce{MnO4- + 8H+ + 5e- &-> Mn^2+}& 
   E(\text{Red}) &= \pu{1.23 V}\tag{c}\label{c}\\
   \ce{MnO4- + 4H+ + 3e- &-> MnO2 + 2H2O}& 
   E(\text{Red}) &=\pu{1.6 V}\tag{d}\label{d}
   \end{align}
2. Then figure out the reaction with the highest reduction potential, because according to $E = E(\text{Red}) - E(\text{Ox})$, $E$ is maximal with the biggest $E(\text{Red})$ and the reaction is going to happen with the highest $E$.

   In my example, $\eqref{d}$ has the highest potential, so according to my theory $\ce{MnO2}$ is formed in the reduction of $\ce{MnO4-}$ (in combination with for example the oxidation of $\ce{I-}$. But in all textbooks, internet sites, the reduction $\eqref{c}$ is named - not reaction $\eqref{d}$ which I had determined.

I am aware that these potentials are pH- and concentration dependent, I fit the $E(\text{Red})$-data with the Nernst-Equation to $\mathrm{pH} = 3$. Nevertheless, $E(\text{Red})$ of $\eqref{d}$ is always higher in $E(\text{Red})$ than $\eqref{c}$. According to my calculations (graph of $\eqref{d}$) which is dependent on the $\mathrm{pH}$ is always higher than $\eqref{c}$).

I have drawn a diagram which shows the $E(\text{Red})$ potential of the two reaction $\eqref{c}$ and $\eqref{d}$ (see legend). Reaction $\eqref{d}$ has always the higher standard potential - is the better oxidation reaction. Why does nevertheless reaction $\eqref{d}$ happen in acid solutions?

[image]

Functions calculated with Nernst-Equation:
\begin{align}
E(\text{pH}) &= 1.507 - \frac{0.059}{5} \cdot 8 \text{pH}\tag{c'}\\
E(\text{pH}) &= 1.7 - \frac{0.059}{3} \cdot 4 \text{pH}\tag{d'}
\end{align}
(other concentrations are assumed as equal)

Comment: Please check some unbalance equations and corresponding $\mathrm{E^o}$ (red) values in equations (a)-(d).

Answer (score 1):

What you have listed are standard redox potentials. You need two of them to determine a reaction. As I'm not sure what reaction you intend, I'll give an example below, which you can use to work out your own reaction. The diagram helps to sort out what can happen.

[image: redox diagram]

Note that a reducing agent is an electron donor, and an oxidising agent an electron acceptor and $$\ce{oxidised form + electrons <=> reduced form}.$$

For example:
The oxidiser $\ce{Sn^{2+}}$ reacts completely with reducer $\ce{Cr^{2+}}$ (at standard redox potentials).
\begin{align}
E^\circ &= \pu{-0.136 V}:&
\ce{Sn^2+ + 2e- &<=> Sn}\\ 
E^\circ &= \pu{-0.41 V}:&
\ce{Cr^3+ + e^- &<=> Cr^2+}\\
&&
\ce{2Cr^2+ + Sn^2+  &<=>> 2Cr^3+ + Sn v}
\end{align}
With energy 
$$E= (\pu{-0.136 V}) - (\pu{-0.41 V}) = \pu{0.274 V}$$
 which corresponds to a negative free energy and hence is spontaneous: 
\begin{align}
\Delta G &= -nFE= (-2\times  96485\times 0.274) \pu{J};& 
(\pu{1J} &= \pu{1C*V}).
\end{align}

Although the reverse reaction, $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ to oxidise $\ce{Sn}$ metal could occur, this happens to a negligible extent.

Comment: First thank you for your answer,
I understand your point, but if I look at following reaction:

2I<sup>-</sup> -> I<sub>2</sub> + 2e<sup>-</sup> E(Red) = -0.536 V

with c) $\Delta E =$ E(Red) - E(Ox) = 1.23 V + 0.536 V = 1,766 V

with d) $\Delta E =$ E(Red) - E(Ox) = 1.6V + 0.536 V = 2,136 V

=> reaction d) (in redox with the I<sup>-</sup> oxidation) will happen according to the "theory" - but in reality, there is no brown, dirty solution - clear, weak pink (indicates c)!)

Comment: OK, bad example. Its brown from the I<sub>2</sub>. But all reactions in the internet and books claim the formation of Mn<sup>2+</sup>...